# jquery UI tabs fx options

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I have two tabs. This, I do not want to change.

What I **do** want to change is the fx option or write a function in the select event.

```
  select: function(event, ui) { slide 'ui.panel' left or right; return false; }
```

When I execute this code, nothing happens.

I want to simply slide the left div from left in and the right div from right in.

Any suggestions?